# Elastic Beanstalk SymLink in my node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have node application I'm trying to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk. I was following an [article I had read to write my app to be more more modular](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/modular-node-js-express/) it recommends adding a SymLink from the node_modules folder into my lib folder with the modularized code that I wrote so allow the dependencies to be shared easier. This worked perfectly when I was testing my server, but when I tried to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk it didn't work I read up a bit on the .ebextentions and I tried making a file called 01symlink.config :

```
container_commands:
  symlink:
    command: "ln -s ../lib _"
    cwd: "./node_modules"
```

I tried the cwd in a couple different ways:
`node_modules`
`/var/app/current/node_modules`

But they all end up with the same error:

`Unhandled exception during build: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node_modules'`

Is there a folder tree map of the server Elastic Beanstalk puts up, or is there just a better way of doing this?

Comment: I also want to know this

Comment: @Wayneio I don't think theres actually a way to do this, and at least from my conversations on the node irc its not recommended to have you a symlink between the modularized code and the main server as it can cause dependency conflicts